# Is it possible to duplicate the behavior of 'tail -f /var/log/maillog' with systemctl status?

Tags: centos, systemd, postfix

On a CentOS 7.3 server, I would like to watch the logs in real time for postfix. I can currently see some detail by issuing:

systemctl status postfix -l

However, this exits. I want a command I can run that will show me the journal entries as they appear and not exit until I want it to. Any ideas?

Comment: The duplicate Q is now listed at the top of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo journalctl -fu postfix
```

See `man journalctl` for details.